# hgweb: display different repositories to different users?

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I'd like to host two different sets of private repositories off the same server/vhost, and have users see one set or another depending on their credentials.

Is there an easier way of doing this than hosting two [separate](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Public_and_Private_Repositories-1) hgweb instances with separate user accounts and config files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, nothing prevents you from having this line:

```
allow_read = user1 user2 user3
```

in `.hg/hgrc` of half of your repos, and:

```
allow_read = user4 user5 user6
```

in the other half. Even to *see* the repo in the list, the user has to be in the `allow_read` list.

However, managing this can prove cumbersome.

Comment: @Gili, thanks for the RhodeCode hint! Replaced our HgWeb install with it and I'm happy (but yes, setup was a pain).